# Apacheの再インストールに挑戦中。http://localhost/が表示されなくて困っています

Tags: windows, apache

https://techacademy.jp/magazine/1846 を参考に
WindowsServer2012R2=64bit筐体にApache2.4をインストールしようとしています。
一応作業的にはインストールを終え、サービスをStartさせているつもりですが、当該サーバのブラウザに"it works"が現れず、ド壷にはまっています。（IE：x86とx64　両方試してもダメ）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【事象発生までの行動】
・こちらの筐体はかつて、Apache2.**2**が動作しておりましたが、今朝アンインストールを実施しました。

・先に記載したサイトで、Apache2.4のフォルダをCドライブ直に配置した上、インストールの作業を行うよう指示がありますが、これに逆らいc:\ProgramFilesの直下に配置した上でhttpd -k installをコマンド指示してインストールを終えています。

・すぐさま当該サービスを起動させようとしましたが、httpd.confが見当たらないみたいなエラーが表示されたので、Apache2.4のフォルダをCドライブ直におき直し、再度サービス起動を試行したことで一応に起動に成功した模様です。

・コントロールパネル内プログラムと機能（旧：プログラムの追加と削除）メニューに、Apache2.4の羽アイコンの行が見当たらないのが気になっています。ちなみに再度インストールの指示をすると、既にインストールされているのメッセージが現れます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

====質問====
Apache2.4が正常にインストールできているかの確認、
サービスを稼動させたことで、無事当該サーバのブラウザにit worksを表すための手立てをご教示ください。（何が問題で現事象が生じているのか特定できていないので、曖昧な質問になってしまいました、ご容赦下さい）

インターネットに接続できない筐体のため、皆様がよくいうxamppというユーティリティの利用をあきらめています。今朝インストールのためにApacheのサイトから取得したファイルは「httpd-2.4.29-Win64-VC15」です。

年末のお忙しいところ恐縮ですが、皆様の暖かいご支援をお待ち申し上げております。

Comment: Apacheのアクセスログ・エラーログは確認しないのでしょうか？

Comment: @sayuri 仰られているとおりですね、失礼しました。ただ今error.ogを確認しましたが、Cドライブ直下にApache2.2フォルダを配置した際の、サービス起動時のログが残っていました。（指定されたファイルがみつかりません）　現在インストール時にapache2.2フォルダを配置していたc:\Program Filesに丸ごと戻しました。その上でサービス起動のコマンドを実行してもログの記載はされないようです。

Comment: それを踏まえて質問を推敲し直されては？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「プログラムの機能」の一覧に表示されるのはいわゆるインストーラ(EXEやMSI形式)のファイルを実行してインストールした場合のみです。今回はZipアーカイブを展開しているだけなので当然一覧には表示(登録)されません。

今回コマンドプロンプトで実施しているインストールはApacheをバックグラウンドで実行するための**サービス**をWindowsに登録する作業で、普段のWindowsアプリをインストールしているのとは少し意味合いが違います。
一度`Program Files (x86)`以下に`Apache`フォルダを置いて`httpd -k install`を実行しているので、その後に`C:\`直下にフォルダだけ移動してもサービスの登録は以前の場所で残ったままになっているのだと思います。

念のためApacheを元の`Profram Files (x86)`配下に戻し、起動を試してみてください。`httpd.confが見つからない`などのエラーが出ていたとのことですが、もう一度表示されるメッセージを確認してください。
(表示されていた通り単純に`httpd.conf`が存在しないのが原因かもしれません。エラーメッセージにはきちんと意味があるので、見るだけでなく読んで意味を理解してください)

Comment: ご見解・ご支援を賜りまして誠にありがとうございます。
結果から述べますと、現在はhttp://localhost/にアクセスすると"it works"の表示に成功しています。
Apache2.4フォルダをご見解どおり、インストール時の環境C:\Program Filesへ戻し
サービスを起動してみて、表れたエラーメッセージを解析することにしました。


"ServerRoot must be a valid directory"と表れていたので、
httpd.confという定義ファイル上でServerRootというキーワードを検索すると
Apache2.4フォルダが、Cドライブ直下のパス記載になっていたので、修正してみました。
この上でサービスの起動にリトライすると、次にhtdocsというフォルダに関しても同様のメッセージが表れたので
こちらについてもパスを修正しました（C:\Apache2と記載された部分はC:\Program Files￥Apache2.4に一律変更）。

再度サービスを起動してみると、エラーがでなくなったので
localhostにアクセスしてみると．．．無事　"it works"を表示することができました。ご指摘が功を奏しました、重ねてお礼を申し上げます。

プログラムと機能メニューに表れない事象は普通なのですね。