# uninstall.exeがない状態でアンインストールを達成したい

Tags: xampp

[別案件](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/42628/19110)で、XAMPP経由でセットアップしたPHPのみをVerUpする手立てについて、問合せておりましたがXAMPP一式を入れ替える方針へ転換することとしました。
現在当方の端末に入っているXAMPPは、Eclipse Oxygen4.7という日本語化パックの入手から達成したものです、こちらにこのXAMMPPが含まれていたのです。（参考したのは https://techacademy.jp/magazine/1620 ）

XAMPPの入れ替え、ということでよくインターンネットの記事にあるように、現行のものをuninstall.exeによりアンインストールする！！ことから始めたかったのですが．．．．
このexeがないのです、当方のXAMPPに。
（readmeを参照すると、ApacheFriends XAMPP Version 5.6.32の記載あり）

#### 質問

どのような手続きを踏めば、XAMPPのアンインストールを達成することができるのでしょうか？
XAMPPという名目でなく、PHP・APACHE・MYSQLなどの個々でもよろしいです。
XAMPPのフォルダを消すだけで、良かったりするのでしょうか？
次にセットアップしようとしているXAMPP（xampp-win32-7.0.28-0-VC14-installer）の障害の要因にさえならなければ　良いのです．．．．

いつもすみませんが、暖かなご支援をよろしくお願いいたします

===追記===
普通にApacheFriendsのページにいって、PHP7.0が含まれるXAMPPを自分の端末用に選択（xampp-win32-7.0.28-0-VC14-installer）、当該exeを実行したところ、[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
というダイアログが現われました。これは狙っていたZIP版でないということ？？ですかね？
zip版は一体どこからダウンロードできるのだろうか．．．．

Comment: この質問は「uninstall.exeが見つからない状態で(Eclipse同梱の)XAMPPをアンインストールするには？」だったはずです。なぜ追記でインストールの話になっているのかが不明です。質問内容は「一問一答」で完結するようにしてください。また、追記で表示されているダイアログは「UACの設定によりProgram Filesへの書き込みが出来ないので、管理者権限でインストーラを実行するか、UACを無効にするように」です。

Comment: @cubick いつもお世話になっております。時間を空けてしまい申し訳ございませんでした。
仰るとおりで返す言葉もございません。
下にご見解頂きました内容で、当問合せ主旨については自分も納得の回答を既に得ていますので
本件としては終結させたいと思います。
度重なる不手際を何卒ご容赦ください。
追記した「PHP7.0が含まれるXAMPPを自分の端末用にインストールしようしてエラーを招いている」件は
別案件として掲載させて頂きます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

今回使用されているXAMPPはEclipseに同梱された**Zip版**だと思われるので、アンインストールするには事前にApacheやMySQLのサービスを停止・登録を解除したうえでフォルダごと削除するだけです。

公式サイトのFAQにも手順の記載があります。

[How do I uninstall XAMPP?](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html)

> If you installed XAMPP using the ZIP and 7zip versions, shut down all XAMPP servers and exit all panels. If you installed any services, uninstall and shut them down too. Now simply delete the entire folder where XAMPP is installed. There are no registry entries and no environment variables to clean up.

なお、Windowsにおけるインストーラ版とZip版との違いについては過去にも[関連質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/40618/3060)に対する[回答で簡単な解説](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/40620/3060)をしています。

---

以下は余談です。

過去にも「[Apacheの再インストール](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/40620/3060)」や「[Apache+PHPの動作確認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/41822/3060)」等の質問をされており、既にそれなりの動作環境はあったにも関わらず、今回またEclipseの導入をきっかけにあえて同梱のXAMPPに手を出された理由がイマイチ分かりません。
毎回対象は別PCで、別々の方法で環境を構築しようとしているという事でしょうか？

Comment: 貴重なご意見をありがとうございます。過去の問合せ案件でもお世話・拝見頂いた方からすると
saya24は一体何をしているのか？想像ができませんよね？
以前開発端末でPHPによるサイトを仕上げ、サーバでも稼動を果たしました。
この時、参考書片手にPHPを開発していった関係で、全てJSも含めエディタで仕上げていきました。

手始めとしては確かにエディタでスタートしても良かったのですが、相応のWebページのサイトなので
世間一般同様、エクリプスでの管理・開発スタイルに切替えるべきでは？？　と思いたったわけです。
（この為に新たな開発端末を手配しました、本当はCAKEPHPを使い出したいところですが、
まだこの理解が足りなく、次のサイト開発でチャレンジするつもり）


いずれにしも、フォルダの削除でクリーンになるという情報を頂けたのは本当に本当に助かりました。
Eclipseのフォルダをまるっと消すことで、この中にXAMPPも含まれているので削除されます。

その後の再セットアップは、最初にXAMPPを入れて、あとから単体Eclipseを入手してセットアップする感じかな～．．．
今回良く中身も確認せず楽してEclipseのALL IN ONE（Oxygen）を入れて、苦しんだ私でした

Answer (score 1):

入れ替える、消した後で新たにインストールし直す、ということなら、フォルダを削除してインストールでいいと思います
それでなにか不具合が起きるというのは経験してませんね

Comment: @わいわい　ありがとうございます。良く確認もせず楽してAll IN ONEのEclipseを入れてしまったことで
混乱してしまいました。
これから開発環境の構築を再チャレンジしていくわけですが、
XAMPPでAPACHE・PHPを入れた上、PHP用のEclipseをセットアップする考えでいます。
会社の端末だから、XAMPPのセットアップ方法は提供サイトとCall&Responseで進めていくタイプだと
プロキシサーバの絡みで多分うまくいかない。そう睨んでいて、ZIP版でセットアップすることができれば、と考えています。
（前回Eclipse ALL IN ONE Oyxgenはzipだった）
XAMPPがZIP版を提供していないとなると．．．．頭が痛いんだけれど